bash: is it possible to make `errexit` work inside conditionals?
Consider the following script:
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit -o xtrace

qux() {
        false
        echo QUX
}

quux() {
        qux ||:
        echo QUUX
}

quux

Running this script produces:
+ quux
+ qux
+ false
+ echo QUX
QUX
+ echo QUUX
QUUX

In other words, not only does quux ignore the return code of qux, it also causes qux discard non-zero error codes within itself, a somewhat counterintuitive behavior.
Until now, I have been writing scripts under the assumption that set -o errexit terminates the shell whenever a program or function returns a non-zero code. However, I discovered that errexit doesn't work inside conditionals. Instead, it functions like a global switch that conditionals turn off until they are evaluated.
Is it possible to make set -o errexit work inside conditionals? Is there a shell that supports it?

This sounds a lot like Has anyone tried to write a shell that fixes errexit (set -e)? and BashFAQ/105. You've discovered the reason errexit isn't very useful, and it seems that a more useful variant of it is sadly just wishful thinking.

zsh has set -o errreturn that might do what you want (if that is to return early from qux () with the exit status from false)
